# SQL compare data from two tables then return value from different column if conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

- **Environment:** MS Access
- **Technical Area:** SQL/Query
- **Situation:**

  I have 2 tables, tblA, tblB.
  tblA contains 9000 products information       ==> SKU, UPC
  tblB contains manufacture 1500 products  Info ==> sku, UPC
  The problem is the UPC on tblA has either: blank, corrupted UPC and good UPC.
  How can I:

  1. Lookup and update good UPC from tblB if tblA!UPC is blank
  2. Determine if UPC on tblA is corrupred (e.g: 812440000000, 8450+11) then    lookup matching UPC on tblB. If no match found, return "blank"
  3. Keep good UPC on tblA if no matching UPC was found on tblB

I want the good UPC to be updated on tblA instead of just viewing it as query.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I created some sample data like this (and let me know if the setup of the sample data is incorrect):

```
create table tblA
(
    sku varchar(25),
    upc varchar(25)
)
go
create table tblB
(
    sku varchar(25),
    upc varchar(25)
)
go

insert into tblA values ('sku1', null)
insert into tblB values ('sku1', 'correct upc #1!')
insert into tblA values ('sku2', 'CORRUPT UPC!')
insert into tblB values ('sku2', 'correct upc #2!')
insert into tblA values ('sku3', 'CORRUPT UPC WITH NO MATCH!')
```

Then I run these update commands:

First, for your point #1:

```
update tblA set upc = tblB.upc
from tblA
inner join tblB on tblA.sku = tblB.sku and tblA.upc is null
```

Then for your point #2:

```
update tblA set upc = isnull(tblB.upc, '')
from tblA
left join tblB on tblA.sku = tblB.sku 
where tblA.upc like 'CORRUPT%' 
-- you'll need to specify the actual criteria that makes a upc corrupted,
-- and replace the "like 'CORRUPT%'" clause!
```

Afterward, this query:

```
select * from tblA
```

Gives you:

```
--sku   upc
--sku1  correct upc #1!
--sku2  correct upc #2!
--sku3  <blank>
```

Any (uncorrupted) upc in tblA without a corresponding sku in tblB would be left alone. Does that put you on the right track?

Comment: Here is the working SQL tested within Access Update query: UPDATE [tblA] INNER JOIN [tblB] ON [tblA].sku = [tblB].[V SKU] SET [tblA].upc = [tblB]![UPC Code]
WHERE ((([tblA].upc) Like '*0000*')) OR ((([tblA].upc) Is Null));